# Sudden jump in particular crash(NoClassDefFoundError) in fabric

Tags: android

Can any one please help with debugging following crash log

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: us
       at up.(SourceFile:145)
       at ixc.e(SourceFile:250)
       at bqf.run(SourceFile:74)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I got above crash log from fabric, So I don't know why this is happening. 
99% of time it is in Android version 4.3 to 4.4.4

Comment: No idea, I can not see this anywhere in my code. @RajenRaiyarela

Comment: I've also seen crashes like this a lot. Mainly samsung tablet. Are you using youtube_android_player sdk?

Comment: Yes I am using youtube android player sdk.